# How To Install Chrome Browser Into cPanel Linux Hosting

Tags: python, selenium, cpanel

[I deploy the project to Cpanel hosting using Linux os. And I also downloaded ChromeDrive for Linux at the site: [https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html?path=103.0.5060.53/][1]

With absolute path as follows

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r'/home/gettaing/seleniumtest/chromedriver',options=chrome_options)
```

And I also tried ChromeDrive for Windows but got the same error.

> WebDriverException at / Message: unknown error: cannot find Chrome binary

Then I try to install pybrowsers to check if the web browser is installed or not

```
pip install pybrowsers
print(browsers.get("chrome"))
```

And the result is None

Comment: Did you install google-chrome in addition to the webdriver?

Comment: My computer runs windows operating system and I have Chrome web browser installed. I run Project locally, it's normal. But when running at hosting, the error is reported as above

Comment: Did you install chrome web browser on the system that you're trying to run selenium?

Comment: I don't know how to install chrome web browser for cPanel

Comment: You can install software on cPanel server the same way you would install on any Linux system

Comment: I have never installed software for linux via terminal. Can you just help me

Comment: I have tried su and sudo and both give me the error command not found :(
Pictures of the error: https://i.imgur.com/tAMJcwi.png

Comment: Sorry, I thought that this was a cPanel server you controlled. If you only have cPanel access as a regular user, you can not install software on it in that way and will need to contact the admin of the server. Shared hosting comes with a lot of limitations.

Comment: yes let me try contact. Thank you for suggesting to help me.